# Static member accessed via instance reference (using 'this' keyword)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static, instance

```
public class RoundCapGraph extends View {
   static private int strokeWidth = 20;

   public void setStrokeWidth(int strokeWidth){
       this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
       //warning : static member 'com.example.ud.RoundCapGraph.strokeWidth' accessed via instance reference
   }
}
```

In android studio I'm trying to set strokeWidth using setStrokeWidth.
But I get warning
**static member 'com.example.ud.RoundCapGraph.strokeWidth' accessed via instance reference**

Question : Does 'this' keyword make new instance and access variable via new instance?

EDITED : I don't really need to set strokeWidth variable static, but I want to understand why using 'this' keyword produce particular warning

Comment: Create the object of `RoundCapGraph ` using `new` operator and then use it.

Comment: @chiragsoni that's a terrible idea :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` keyword doesn't create a new instance, but `this.` is usually used to access instance variables.

Therefore, when the compiler sees that you try to access a `static` variable via `this.`, it assumes that you might have made a mistake (i.e. that your intention was to access an instance variable), so it warns about it.

A better way to access the `static` variable is:

```
RoundCapGraph.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
```

EDIT: you are setting your `static` variable within an instance method. This is a good indication that the compiler was right in warning you about accessing the `static` variable as if it was an instance variable.

You should set `static` variables via `static` methods, and set instance variables via instance methods.

Comment: In other words, `this` doesn't create an instance unless you use it like `this(/*...*/)` (but that's another story), when we use `this` we're referring to the instance object will be created using the class.

Answer (score 1):

When you access static member using object's instance, the instance gets replace by Class. i.e `this.strokeWidth` would be replace with `RoundCapGraph.strokeWidth`

There will be no `NullPointerException` due to the instance replacement.

I found a reference to this in the [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11): Chapter 15, Section 11: Field Access Expressions.

> **Example 15.11.1-2. Receiver Variable Is Irrelevant For static Field Access**
>
> *The following program demonstrates that a null reference may be used to access a class (static) variable without causing an exception*

```
public class RoundCapGraph extends View {
   static private int strokeWidth = 20;

   public void setStrokeWidth(int strokeWidth){
       RoundCapGraph roundCapGraph = null;
       roundCapGraph.strokeWidth = strokeWidth; // NullPointerException?
       //warning : static member 'com.example.ud.RoundCapGraph.strokeWidth' accessed via instance reference
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct, Static members belong to the class not to an instance.

Comment: the question was `Does 'this' keyword make new instance and access variable via new instance?` so you might want to rework your answer :)